# Generate matrix with for-loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

Say I have two functions f(x), g(x), and a vector:

```
xval=1:0.01:2
```

For each of these individual x values, I want to define a vector of y-values, covering the y-interval bounded by the two functions (or possibly a matrix where columns are x-values, and rows are y-values).

How would I go about creating a loop that would handle this for me? I have absolutely no idea myself, but I'm sure some of you have something right up your sleeve. I've been sweating over this problem for a few hours by now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wish to generate a matrix, I assume the number of values between f(x) and g(x) should be the same for every `xval`. Let's call that number of values `n_pt`. Then, we also know what the dimensions of your result matrix `rng` will be.

```
n_pt = 10;
xval = 1 : 0.01 : 2;
rng = zeros(n_pt, length(xval));
```

Now, into the loop. Once we know what the y-values returned by f(x) and g(x) are, we can use `linspace` to give us `n_pt` equally spaced points between them.

```
for n = 1 : length(xval)
  y_f = f(xval(n))
  y_g = g(xval(n))
  rng(:, n) = linspace(y_f, y_g, n_pt)';
end
```

This is nice because with `linspace` you don't need to worry about whether `y_f > y_g`, `y_f == y_g` or `y_f < y_g`. That's all taken care of already.

For demsonstration, I run this example for `xval = 1 : 0.1 : 2` and the two sinusoids `f = @(x) sin(2 * x)` and `g = @(x) sin(x) * 2`. The points are plotted using `plot(xval, rng, '*k');`.
[image: Example]

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant, that is exactly what I was looking for. It is very much appreciated, I don't think I'd ever figure that out myself.

Thanks again.